# Chamar função php usando onblur (concluído)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Tenho um evento **onblur** pra chamar uma função e essa função tem que chamar uma classe php pra poder comparar o que foi digitado no input com o que está no meu BD, mas não sei fazer isso usando jquery, como faço isso?

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Validação de campos com AJAX</title>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/ajax/check_cnae.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

Login: <br /> <input type="text" id="cnae" onblur="validarDados('cnae', document.getElementById('cnae').value);" />
<div id="campo_cnae"> </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**classe**

```
require_once "Conexao.class.php";

class Socio {    
  private $con;
  private $cnae; 

public function __construct(){
    $this->con = new Conexao();
}

public function __set($atributo, $valor){
    $this->$atributo = $valor;
}

public function __get($atributo){
    return $this->$atributo;
}

public function cnae(){
    $this->cnae = $_GET['valor'];
        $validar = $this->con->conectar()->prepare("SELECT cnae FROM cnae WHERE cnae = ?");
        $validar->execute(array($this->cnae));   
        if($validar->rowCount() == 0){
            echo "CNAE invalido.";
        }else{
            echo "CNAE valido.";
        }
}
```

**script**

```
var req;

function validarDados(campo, valor) {

// Verificar o Browser
// Firefox, Google Chrome, Safari e outros
if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
   req = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
// Internet Explorer
else if(window.ActiveXObject) {
   req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

// Aqui vai o valor e o nome do campo que pediu a requisição.
var url = "../../index_teste2.php?campo="+campo+"&valor="+valor;

// Chamada do método open para processar a requisição
req.open("Get", url, true);

// Quando o objeto recebe o retorno, chamamos a seguinte função;
req.onreadystatechange = function() {

// Exibe a mensagem "Verificando" enquanto carrega
if(req.readyState == 1) {
    document.getElementById('campo_' + campo + '').innerHTML = '<font color="gray">Verificando...</font>';
}

// Verifica se o Ajax realizou todas as operações corretamente (essencial)
if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
// Resposta retornada pelo validacao.php
var resposta = req.responseText;

// Abaixo colocamos a resposta na div do campo que fez a requisição
document.getElementById('campo_'+ campo +'').innerHTML = resposta;
}
}
req.send(null);
}
```

**arquivo PHP que recebe instanciamento**

```
require_once 'classes/Socio.class.php';

$socio = new Socio();

if(isset($_GET['valor'])){
    $dados = $socio->cnae($_GET['valor']);
}
```

Comment: Você precisa fazer, na função `validarDados()`, uma chamada Ajax para algum arquivo PHP e esse arquivo deve fazer a verificação, depois é só você retornar algum resultado com o PHP e tratar no JavaScript.

Comment: É justamente essa parte que eu não sei @GabrielQueirozSchicora, to vendo uns videos no youtube pra ver se ajuda.

Comment: Coloquei um exemplo nas respostas

Comment: @GabrielQueirozSchicora eu cheguei a colocar um script em ajax, mas eu não consigo acessar a minha **function cnae**, vou editar e colocar o script que tentei.

Comment: Você está mandando uma requisição para sua classe(`Socio.class.php`), mas quando chega lá, nada acontece, porque em lugar nenhum está sendo chamado sua função `cnae`, ela está apenas sendo criada, então você teria que chamar ela em algum lugar `cnae();` ou, como seria o mais correto na minha opnião, criar um arquivo separado que vai instanciar sua classe e chamar a função cnae, como está exemplificado na minha resposta, afinal mandar uma requisição ajax para uma classe eu acho que não é uma boa prática.

Comment: @GabrielQueirozSchicora, consegui obter o resultado que queria, mas só tem um problema, o retorno fica duplicando meu **input** e não consegui achar o erro, [link]http://www.acivg.com/index_teste.php, editei o código pra ver como ficou, não usei o seu exemplo mais abriu a mente.

Comment: @GabrielQueirozSchicora, obrigado pela dica, consegui obter o resultado e resolvi o problema da duplicação do input, estava instanciando no mesmo arquivo php que recebia a resposta, tive que separar e fazer em 4 arquivos, agora ta funcionando do jeito que eu quero.

Comment: Que bom que resolveu, precisando estamos ai.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente uma função Ajax funciona com essa estrutura (Estou colocando um exemplo, você precisa adaptar para seu uso).

Esse script vai fazer uma requisição para o arquivo `verificaDado.php` utilizando o metodo `GET`. Também está explicito que vai ser passado dados do tipo `json` e retornado do tipo `html`, eu estou presumindo que você retorne apenas um `true` ou `false`, caso vá retornar algo mais complexo (um array por exemplo) é preciso mudar para `dataType: 'json'` e no php mudar para `echo json_encode($seuArray)`.

Seguem os códigos de exemplo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Essa variável recebe o valor do input
    var inputVal = $('input').val();

    $.ajax({
      type: "get",
      url: "verificaDado.php",
      data: { value: inputVal },
      dataType: 'html',
      contentType: "json"
  }).done(function(obj) {
    //Caso de tudo certo com o ajax vai cair aqui e a variavel obj é o retorno
  }).fail(function(){
    //Caso ocorra alguma falha no ajax cai aqui
  });

</script>
```

No PHP:

```
 $socio = new Socio();

 //O echo funciona como o retorno para o ajax, então o que for mostrado na tela vai voltar para o Ajax
 echo $socio->funcao_para_verificar($_GET['value']);
```